# Arch Linux - slow boot because of start job

Tags: wireless-networking, boot, arch-linux

My Arch Linux's boot has been slow because of a start job running that adds 90 seconds to boot time. It reads, `A start job is running for /sys/subsystem/net/devices/wlan0`. How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem just now after installing Arch Linux on a new laptop.

In the archiso installer environment, as well as within the `arch-chroot` environment for my new installation, my wireless network card appeared in the old-school style as "wlan0". I wanted to use `wpa_supplicant`, so I enabled the device-specific wpa_supplicant systemd service with `systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0`.

After booting for the first time and experiencing the problem you described, I checked my network interfaces with `ip link` and saw that my wireless card now appeared with a new-school [predictable network name](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) like `wlp1s3`. Since my systemd service depended on an interface which didn't exist in my new installation (wlan0), it was timing out waiting for that interface to come up.

So I solved the problem by simply disabling the old service with `systemctl disable wpa_supplicant@wlan0`, and enabling a new one with `systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlp1s3`. Your particular solution will most likely be somewhat different, but I suspect that you probably have the same underlying problem. After logging in, check the names of your network interfaces. If there isn't any wlan0, look for a systemd service which depends on wlan0 and update it to use the correct network interface name.